# Discrete wavelet transform and complex wavelet transform

Tags: wavelet, haar-wavelet, wavelet-transform

I want to use dwt in Octave, and I don't know what is wname.
The function is:
[u v] = dwt(noisy_signal,'wname');
wname is the wavelet name, I used haar but it is appeared as invalid function.
Can anybody help me please?

And for complex wavelet transform, I used dual tree complex wavelet transform, is this function the best?
And does this function need to a specific filter?

Thanks in advance, 
Weam

Comment: 'is this function best' for what?

Comment: I meant that (is it the best for extracting features to help in processing the distorting signals?).

Answer (score 0):

`wname`(wavelet name) is the type of mother wavelet you want to use.
the function you used:

```
[u v]=dwt(signal,'haar');
```

There is no problem in it. You must take a finite signal. That's it. It will give you single level 1-D wavelet transform. Where `u`=approximate coefficients and `v`=detailed coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But Do you have any idea about the other types such as db4, comr and morlet and complex morlet. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are different kind of mother wavelet families present. 'db4' is of family 'daubechies' and others have their respective families.The shape of is wavelet is different.If you want information about them ,then search "waveletfamilies" in matlab.